# Promise { pending }, async, await in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm trying to understand why this code returns "Promise { pending }".

```
const reduceDirections = (str) => {
    str = str.replace(/northsouth|southnorth|eastwest|westeast/ig, '')

            if (str.search(/northsouth|southnorth|eastwest|westeast/ig) === -1) {
                str = str.replace(/south|north|west|east/gi, '$& ').replace(/(^\s+|\s+$)/,'')
                console.log(str)
                return str

            } else {
                reduceDirections(str)
            }  
}

async function start(arr) {
    str = arr.join('')
    let res = await reduceDirections(str)
    return Promise.resolve(res)
}

console.log(start(["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]))
```

When I `console.log(str)`from the reduceDirections() function I can see I have the result I want. But when I (one line later) `return str` I instead have "Promise pending"

I'm sorry for not understanding Promises and async await. I have tried to read on mdn and watch videos but I don't see how I can transfer that they show to this problem. Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: `reduceDirections` does not have anything asynchronous in it, so what do you expect `await`ing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

1) There is nothing asynchronous happening in `reduceDirections`, nor does it return a promise, so it makes no sense to use `await` on it.

2) The recursive part of your function does not return the recursive result, so change:

```
 } else {
     reduceDirections(str)
 }
```

to:

```
 } else {
     return reduceDirections(str)
 }
```

Then at least you can hope to have a useful string as return value

3) If you really insist on using `await` on something that is returned synchronously, then you can keep it, but it is unnecessary to do

```
return Promise.resolve(res)
```

... since an `async` function always returns a promise anyway. So just do

```
return res;
```

4) you don't wait for *that* promise to resolve. So you should await it's resolved value and use `console.log` on *that*. Change:

```
console.log(start(["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]))
```

to:

```
start(["NORTH", "SOUTH", "SOUTH", "EAST", "WEST", "NORTH", "WEST"]).then(console.log)
```

But again, using promises is useless here and only complicates the code. You don't get any advantage from it.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why the poster sees what they see on the console.

Comment: @Woody yes it does. Read part 4.

Comment: Thank you so much @trincot for detailed and fast answer! What I apparently was looking for was to solve the problem and maintain as much of my own code as possible. And I realize that what got me in on this "Promise-async-await"-track in the first place was just that I missed the "return" in the "else" clause.

Comment: You're welcome. NB: you should not add that paragraph to your question, since the question should remain ... a question. It is enough to leave this here as a comment, or as a comment under your own question.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - i don't think there is any point getting into argument, but other than the misunderstanding about how async/await work I though there was a subtler question here i.e. why is the promise is *pending* even though the function returned a resolved promise ?

Comment: @Woody, the answer is that the OP doesn't *"wait for that promise to resolve"* (as I wrote in point 4). Do you suggest it should be worded differently?

Comment: @Woody whether or not it's pending is irrelevant, since promises do not provide any interface for synchronous introspection. The point is the return value is a promise and not the unwrapped value.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the first line of the question is "I'm trying to understand why this code returns "Promise { pending }". Given they wrote a function that says return Promise.resolve(res); i think the question about why the promise is pending (and not resolved) is relevant.

Comment: @Woody I'm pretty sure the implied expectation was _"as opposed to `str`"_, not _"as opposed to `Promise { resolved }`"_

Comment: @trincot - waiting for the promise to resolve or not doesn't change the state of the promise returned by the function. i.e. why did the start() function return an *unresolved* Promise ?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you might be right, but the original questioner is not the only person who reads the answers or questions here, so i hardly see how clarifying why the Promise is pending would be "irrelevant" in that context.

Comment: @Woody because if it returned a resolved promise, that has no bearing on whether the value is synchronously accessible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the question to me can be read as "why does a function that appears to explicitly return a resolved promise  actually return a pending promise."   This is a subtler question than "why does it return a weird promise thing at all" for sure, but it's hardly irrelevant given the context. You say "since promises do not provide any interface for synchronous introspection it's irrelevant" but logging them to the console shows their state, and the poster noted the state in the question.